# Two images always in the same position

Tags: html, css, image

I have two pictures:

[image]

and

[image]

I want them to be displayed on a website like this:

[image]

A center of green rectangle should always cover the center of the orange dot, no matter what resolution a screen has and no matter how big the images are(they resize when the browser window resizes).
If the browser window resizes, both images should get resized in the same way (so for  example if image A is 30% smaller than before resizing, image B should also be 30% smaller than before resizing).

How can I get a result like this?

Comment: [Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: if it is always going to be like that, why not simplify it and make the green part of the grey image?  Just seems like you are trying to over complicate things for no reason

Comment: It's just an example of course. My situation is a little bit more complicated, becasue I have a couple of images, and during runtime it'll be decided which one should be displayed - sometimes it will be a green rectangle, sometimes a blue one, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

used css property background-attachment:fixed its may be helped 
read more about background-attachment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp
 or 
add image in div and used position property